# How do I square a number without using multiplication?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, numbers, perfect-square

Was wondering if there is a way to write a method which squares a number (integer or decimal/float) without using the operational sign (`*`). For example: square of `2` will be `4`, square of `2.5` will be `6.25`, and `3.5`'s will be `12.25`.

Here is my approach:

```
def square(num)
  number = num
  number2 = number
  (1...(number2.floor)).each{ num += number }
  num
end

puts square(2) #=> 4 [Correct]
puts square(16) #=> 256 [Correct]
puts square(2.5) #=> 5.0 [Wrong]
puts square(3.5) #=> 10.5 [Wrong]
```

The code works for integers, but not with floats/decimals. What am I doing wrong here? Also, if anybody has a fresh approach to this problem then please share. Algorithms are also welcome. Also, considering performance of the method will be a plus.

Comment: `2.5` to `5.0`.. Is this correct ? How ?

Comment: My bad, it is 6.25. Thanks for catching :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few tricks you could use, arranged here in order of increasing trickery.

### Logarithms

Observe that `k * k = e^log(k*k) = e^(log(k) + log(k))`, and use that rule:

```rb
Math.exp(Math.log(5.2) + Math.log(5.2))
# => 27.04
```

No multiplication here!

### Division

As another commenter suggested, you could take the reciprocal operation, division: `k/(1.0/k) == k^2`. However, this introduces additional floating-point errors, since `k / (1.0 / k)` is two floating-point operations, whereas `k * k` is only one.

### Exponentiation

Or, since this is Ruby, if you want exactly the same value as the floating-point operation and you don't want to use the multiplication operator, you can use the exponentiation operator: `k**2 == k * k`.

### Call a web service

It's not multiplying if you don't do it yourself!

```
require 'wolfram'       # https://github.com/cldwalker/wolfram
query  = 'Square[5.2]'
result = Wolfram.fetch(query)
```

### Blatant cheating

Finally, if you're feeling really cheap, you could avoid actually employing the literal "*" operation, and use something equivalent:

```
n = ...
require 'base64'
n.send (Base64.decode64 'Kg==').to_sym, n    # => n * n
```

Comment: @John - Division has to be: `k/(1.0/k) == k^2` as `1/k` in `k/(1/k) == k^2` will output an integer instead of a decimal value.

@CarySwoveland - I tried `Math.exp(Math.log(5.2) + Math.log(5.2)) #=> 27.04` where as `5.2*5.2 = 27.040000000000003` Which is almost equal if we consider 3 decimal points to be exact. Don't you think?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Ah, yes, I only meant to imply that the specific example I was using gives the mathematically exact value -- not that it was true for every value.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't use any operation sign.

```
def square(num)
  num.send 42.chr, num
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the inverse of multiplication is division, so you can get the same result* by dividing by its inverse. That is: `square(n) = n / (1.0 / n)`. Just make sure you don't inadvertently do integer division.

*Technically dividing twice introduces a second opportunity for rounding error in floating-point arithmetic since it performs two operations. So, this will not produce *exactly* the same result as floating-point multiplication - but this was also not a requirement in the question.

Comment: That's not equivalent to floating-point multiplication. You made two divisions and accumulated 2 errors (`1/n`, `n/(1/n)`) instead of 1 error (`n * n`). If you define `def s(n); n / (1.0 / n);`, you'll get `s(5.1) == 26.009...994` and `5.1**2 == 26.009...998`, which are not equal values.

Comment: @JohnFeminella Valid point, however the OP doesn't specify this as a requirement

Comment: Sure, but if one doesn't require "exact answers", then *any* answer is correct, even wrong ones. Then it's just a question of how wrong is acceptable. :)

Comment: @JohnFeminella Quite true, and point well taken. Although with floating-point arithmetic you don't end up with "exact answers" anyway, do you? :) The question would then go back to why would the OP want to avoid the `*` operator in the first place.

Comment: As @JohnFeminella mentioned. When I tried with (`1/n`, `n/(1/n)`) and it raised **ZeroDivisionError**. So, it has to `(`1.0/n`, `n/(1.0/n)`)` So, it takes the decimal number instead of integer. Nice catch. :)